# Size of void* array

Tags: objective-c

I have an array of parameter keys as follows:

```
void* parameterKeys[] = {
    kSecAttrKeyType,
    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits,
    kSecPublicKeyAttrs,
    kSecPrivateKeyAttrs
};
```

How can I get the length of this array programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length in bytes or number of elements?

Length in bytes: `sizeof(parameterKeys)`

Number of elements: `sizeof(parameterKeys) / sizeof(parameterKeys[0])`